# R Sum numbers within string

Tags: r, string, sum

I have a question:

I have a dataset like this simple example:

```
df<-data.frame(ID=c("A","B","C","D"),
               Score=c("15","16/18/19+2/6","3/+2","19/18/14"))
```

I want to end up with a dataset that has split the `score` numbers. I have a problem with the `/+2` part. when it says `"3/+2"`it actually means: `"3/3+2"` which would finally give `"3/5"`. So what I would like some help with, is to end up with a dataset like this:

```
  ID         Score
  A            15
  B 16/18/19/21/6
  C           3/5
  D      19/18/14
```

I already found out that I can then seperate the score by

```
df<-df %>% 
  mutate(Score = strsplit(as.character(ID), "/")) %>%
  unnest(Score)
```

But I don't know how I can let the numbers duplicate and then sum when /+ occurs, could someone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be probably solved in a more elegant way, but here is one possibility:

```
df %>%
 mutate(Score = strsplit(as.character(Score), "/")) %>%
 unnest() %>%
 rowwise() %>%
 mutate(Score = eval(parse(text = paste0(Score)))) %>%
 group_by(ID) %>%
 mutate(Score = paste0(Score, collapse = "/")) %>%
 distinct()

  ID    Score     
  <fct> <chr>     
1 A     15        
2 B     16/18/21/6
3 C     3/5       
4 D     19/18/14
```

Sample data:

```
df <- data.frame(ID=c("A","B","C","D"),
               Score=c("15","16/18/19+2/6","3/3+2","19/18/14"))
```

It splits "Score" based on /, converts characters to expression by `parse()` and then transforms it back.

Using the data you provided and the pattern from @A. Suliman:

```
df %>%
 mutate(Score = strsplit(gsub("(\\d+)/*\\+(\\d+)","\\1/\\1+\\2", Score), "/")) %>%
 unnest() %>%
 rowwise() %>%
 mutate(Score = eval(parse(text = paste0(Score)))) %>%
 group_by(ID) %>%
 mutate(Score = paste0(Score, collapse = "/")) %>%
 distinct()

  ID    Score        
  <fct> <chr>        
1 A     15           
2 B     16/18/19/21/6
3 C     3/5          
4 D     19/18/14
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) #separate_rows, no need for unnest
df %>% rowwise()%>% 
       mutate(Score_upd=paste0(sapply(unlist(strsplit(gsub('(\\d+)/*\\+(\\d+)','\\1/\\1+\\2',Score),'/')),
       function(x)eval(parse(text = x))),collapse = '/')) %>% 
       separate_rows(Score_upd,sep = '/')

#short version
df %>% mutate(Score=gsub('(\\d+)/*\\+(\\d+)','\\1/\\1+\\2',Score)) %>% 
       separate_rows(Score,sep='/') %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(Score=eval(parse(text=Score))) %>% 
       group_by(ID) %>% summarise(Score=paste0(Score,collapse = '/'))

# A tibble: 4 x 2
  ID    Score        
  <fct> <chr>        
  1 A     15           
  2 B     16/18/19/21/6
  3 C     3/5          
  4 D     19/18/14
```

The main idea is using `gsub` to separate `2+3` correctly, e.g:

```
gsub('(\\d+)/*\\+(\\d+)','\\1/\\1+\\2','20/8/2+3') #/* means 0 or 1 occurence of / e.g, 19+2 and 3/+2.
[1] "20/8/2/2+3"
```

Then

```
valid_str <- gsub('(\\d+)/*\\+(\\d+)','\\1/\\1+\\2','20/8/2+3')
sapply(unlist(strsplit(valid_str,'/')),function(x) eval(parse(text=x)))
20   8   2 2+3 
20   8   2   5 
#OR
sapply(unlist(strsplit(valid_str,'/')),function(x) sum(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(x,'\\+')))))
20   8   2 2+3 
20   8   2   5
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `gsubfn` to do this in a compact way

```
library(gsubfn)
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
   mutate(Score = gsubfn("\\d+\\+\\d+", ~ eval(parse(text = x)), Score))
# ID      Score
#1  A         15
#2  B 16/18/21/6
#3  C        3/5
#4  D   19/18/14
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(ID=c("A","B","C","D"),
           Score=c("15","16/18/19+2/6","3/3+2","19/18/14"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```